# PowerShell copy-item folder structure is NOT wanted

Tags: powershell

The folder named "z:\original" has hundreds of sub-folders containing multiple copies of the same .jpg files. I wanted to copy all .jpg files into a folder named "z:\dump" **WITHOUT** the folder structure and hopefully overwrite most of the copies. I used

```
copy-Item -path "Z:\original" -filter "*.jpg" -Destination "Z:\dump" -recurse -verbose
```

but this recreated the structure with the .jpg files. How can I dump all files into a single folder, using PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

Use combination of dir/Get-ChildItem and Copy-Item with pipeline.

$_.FullName - Full path to jpg file

$_.Name is file name only

```
Get-ChildItem Z:\original\*.jpg -Recurse | %{Copy-Item $_.FullName "Z:\dump\$($_.Name)"}
```

You might need to add -Force to overwrite same files